# Check the values of a matrix and jump in columns, using a recursion function

Tags: python, recursion, matrix

Say I have a matrix of only 0 and 1, something like this:

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

I start from the first column, and to move to the next column there is only three options, which are `[i+1][j+1] or [i][j+1] or [i-1][j+1]`. Clashing into `1` is not allowed. It needs to check those three directions and decide where to move.

preferably I want to go low, so `[i-1][j+1]` is the first option to concider. If not, then `[i][j+1]`, and if not then `[i+1][j+1]`. If there is no way to go further without clashing into `1`, ther is no solution, then the function returns `0`. The goal is to get to the last column in the matrix, in the lowest row possible, and return the number of the row.

I'm writing a code to tell it exactly this, but I dont know what to fill for each `if` condition. How do I tell it to move in those directions, until the end of the matrix?

```
def jumpFromOnes(matrix,i,j):


if(mat[i][j] == 0):
    
    if(matrix[i+1][j+1] !=1 ):
        < fill here >
       
    elif (matrix[i][j+1] !=1):
        < fill here >
        
    elif (i==0 or matrix[i-1][j+1]!=1):
        < fill here >

# This is to tell it where to stop, if it got to the last column or the last row. Dont know if it's correct though.


 if(j+1<len(matrix[0])):
        jumpFromOnes(matrix,i,j+1)
    elif(i+1<len(matrix)):    
        jumpFromOnes(matrix,i+1,0)
    else:
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `i` and `j` indeces with `i+1`, `i-1` or `j+1` depending on which index you are 'jumping' to.

You should do this in a loop so it does it more than once. (If that is what you want)

If it is in a function return it to the outer scope so the indeces are constantly changed. (i.e. the `i` and `j` outside the function should be changed as well)

**Edit:** recursive function

```
def jumpFromOnes(mat,i,j):
    if i==len(matrix)-1: return "Reached end at bottom"
    if j==len(matrix[0])-1: return "Reached end at right"
    if not mat[i+1][j+1]: return jumpFromOnes(mat,i+1,j+1)
    if not mat[i][j+1]: return jumpFromOnes(mat,i,j+1)
    if not mat[i-1][j+1]: return jumpFromOnes(mat,i-1,j+1)
    return "Impossible to continue"
```

This works as it will first check if it reached one of the ends, then if matrix at new position `i+1`, `i-1` or `j+1` equals 0 (as `not 1 -> 0` and `not 0 -> 1`, which are respectively equal to `False` or `True` in python) we return jumpFromOnes at that new position, and if none of the new positions are available, we return impossible to continue.

Comment: I'm supposed to write a recursive function without any kind of loops, no `for` and no `while`. The first part of the code should be the function over one cell, I want to check the possible steps to take. And then I want to call for the function to do that on the rest of the matrix. My problem is writing the function over just one cell, I don't know how to tell it to move across the matrix column by column..